# Forcing a WolframCloud Function to Evaluate

Tags: wolfram-language

I'm using sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com. I define a function f[x] which should return the successor of x, for example f[1] should return 2. However, I get f[1] as output. I've read about Evaluate[] however it does not  seem to help:

```
In[5]:= f[x] := Evaluate[x+1]

In[7]:= Evaluate[f[1]]

Out[7]= f[1]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for `Evaluate`. When defining functions in the Wolfram Language, you've gotta use an underscore after your argument name.

```
f[x_] := x+1;
```

That's because it needs `x` to be a *pattern* to match against. Otherwise the language just treats `x` as a symbol. For more info see this page on [*defining function in the Wolfram Language*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html).